# log shipping process (archive_timeout)

Tags: postgresql, log-shipping

I'm very new in postgresql. I want to ask about log shipping replication process. I know that the timeout parameter is optional in log shipping process. It specifies that we don't want that postgreSQL to wait until the WAL files contain 16 MB to be sent as it does by default. My question is, it is better  has timeout parameter(eg : archive_timeout = 60) or not? is it when we do timeout parameter the process of WAL file in log shipping  is faster than default (the 0 default value indicates that it will until the WAL filled)? why?

I'm sorry i'm still confused in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want timely replication, I suggest enabling streaming replication as well as log shipping.

The main purpose of `archive_timeout` is to ensure that, when you're using log shipping for PITR backups, there's a maximum time window of data loss in situations where the server isn't generating lots of WAL so segment rotation would otherwise be infrequent.

Comment: Thank you for your respond..I'm sorry, i'm not clear, what means by "server isn't generating lots of WAL so segment rotation would otherwise be infrequent"? can you explain more about that? and 1 more thing i also do streaming replication and it is work, but then when i do log shipping it doesn't work, because on the slave the database system is starting up.I refer this step on http://www.themagicnumber.es/replication-in-postgresql-i?lang=en. I using postgresql version 9.3. I hope you can help me.

Comment: @Najwa Well, say you're doing one small INSERT every minute. That'll probably produce less than a kb of WAL per write, so with 16MB segments it'll take `justify_interval(INTERVAL '16384' SECOND)` = about 4 and a half hours before it sends a WAL segment to the archive. You might want it to send much sooner than that so you can guarantee that, say, you lose at most 10 minutes of data in a crash. That's what `archive_timeout` is for.

Comment: it means that, the long time it takes to sends a WAL file segment to the archive, the more high probability data in a crash?

Comment: @Najwa A crash/fire/whatever that causes total loss of the master database (so all you have is archived WAL and your base backups), yes. It doesn't matter for a simple unexpected reboot, postgres server force restart, etc of course, as Pg is crash-safe. But again ... *use streaming replication* and you're generally fine. This option exists mainly to make sure data is available for PITR in bounded time.

Comment: Does a change of the ```archive_timeout``` value require a postgres reload/restart?